# Drew Wilson Auto Suggest Plugin not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, autosuggest

I have my index page INDEX.html and a PHP page TEST.php then an autosuggest javascript code.

I am trying to make an auto suggest search field.

I am not getting autosuggest output.

Only `NO RESULT FOUND` is shown.

Someone please help me to make autosuggest shown in http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin work.

```
<link href="css/autoSuggest.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.autoSuggest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
        <label for="q"></label> <input style="width: 300px;" type="text"
            name="q" id="q" />
        <script type="text/javascript">  
     $(document).ready(function(){      
     $("input[type=text]").autoSuggest("test.php",{minChars: 2, matchCase: false});});  
     </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and PHP looks like this:

```
<?php include("script/core/dbcon.php");  
 $input = $_REQUEST['q'];  
 $data = array();  
 // query your DataBase here looking for a match to $input  
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username LIKE '%$input%'");  
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {  
 $json = array();  
 $json['value'] = $row['id'];  
 $json['name'] = $row['username'];  
 $data[] = $json;  
 }  
 header("Content-type: application/json");  
echo json_encode($data);  
 ?>
```

Comment: Who is Drew Wilson? Also please format your question correctly.

Comment: [Drew Wilson auto suggest plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has now got an AutoComplete method which will do the same

also you should replace

```
$("input[type=text]").auto----
```

with

```
$("#q").auto-----
```